# Ridge regression - what is k=0?

Tags: ridge-regression

I'm getting to know ridge regression and what to check my understanding quickly.

I understand that k is the shrinkage parameter. If I'm reading off coefficients where k=0, is that equivalent to an OLS linear regression?

Or have I got totally the wrong end of the stick?

Simon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming k is the coefficient in front of the regularization term, then yes having k=0 is the same as OLS linear regression.

Comment: Excellent - yes, I believe that we are describing the same parameter using different terms (though please anybody correct me if you think that I am wrong). Thank you so much, Aaron.

Comment: Of course. when you have k equal to zero, you will return to the problem of minimizing $||y - X\beta||^2$ w.r.t $\beta$ .